# How to place a Table at the right side of another Table?

Tags: birt

There are two Tables having their own dataset on my report :

[image]

I want to place the second Table at the right of the first one. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place the two tables in a grid with two columns.

You could even use a third table to do that, but I would use grids if it is only for positioning.